# I have a JSON Object in JavaScript and want to access a key from a String variable

Tags: javascript, html, json, string

In JavaScript, I have a JSON Object. This JSON Object has many keys and I need to access one stored in as a String using the dot operator but am not sure how to do this.

For example, if I have the following JSON code:

```
"values" : [ { "prop0" : "h",
        "prop1" : "pizza",
        "prop2" : "2014-06-24T15:58:50Z",
        "prop3" : ""
      },
      { "prop0" : "paa",
        "prop1" : "cat",
        "prop2" : "2014-06-24T15:58:16Z",
        "prop3" : "mouse"
      }
    ]
```

and I want to access prop1 I would use the following JavaScript code:

```
values[0].prop1;
```

This works so long as I know that the property is called prop1. But I don't know what my properties will be called. I have a String that represents what, in this case, is prop1 or whatever the current property is, however I don't know how to use the dot operator with a String.

I would like something like:

```
values[0].myString;
```

But this does not work.

Is there a way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat a javascript object as an associative array or dictionary by passing it a key to lookup:

`values[0][myString]`

In the following code,

```
var myString = 'prop1';
var val1 = values[0][myString];
var val2 = values[0].prop1;
```

`val1` and `val2` both hold a value of `'pizza'`

Answer (score 0):

**Use bracket notation**.

`values[0].myString` is **equivalent** to `values[0]['myString']` :)

**For example,**

```
var obj = { a : 1 };
obj.a // returns 1
var a_string = 'a';
obj[a_string] // returns 1
```

In general, dot notation looks cleaner but bracket notation is convenient for exactly this purpose.

Comment: but only if `myString` is actually the name of the property.  I think the question is about looking up a property where the name of the property is in a variable.

Comment: Right, I'm just showing that you can pass in a string like a dictionary lookup with a literal, so that means passing in a string variable will work how he expects. Added an example though.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can access properties with dot notation(the way you've been doing it) and with flat bracket notation(i.e. []), so you should be able to access it like this:

values[0][myString]